# Change one element on hover another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've got following piece of html code:

```
<div class="header-menu hide-for-small">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="subtext">
        <li id="menu-item-993"><a>X</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-994"><a>Y</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-995"><a>Z</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="post-filter">..</div>
```

Plus the css:

```css
.post-filter {
    display: none!important;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show `.post-filter` div only when hovered `#menu-item-993`. So im doing:

```css
#menu-item-993:hover .post-filter {
    display:block!important;
}
```

But this just don't work. I've tried to put `+` or `~` between `..:hover` and `.post-filter` - without success. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: you would need to use js to toggle a class on (or show / hide) post filter when menu is hovered.  It can't be done through pure css as there is no parent selector (which you would need to achieve what you want)

Comment: Use javascript for this.....mouseover on menu-item993 calls function that adds display:block; to div.post-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hover` function & add `css` to show and hide it

```
$("#menu-item-993").hover(function(){
  $(".post-filter").css('display','block')
},function(){
  $(".post-filter").css('display','none')
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/95d3m579/)

Comment: cool! one small thing - when I try to hover any of elements (appearing on the div which pops up after hover) it dissapear. I've tried adding position:relative and z-index:100 but still it dissapear:(

Answer (score 2):

Here's a mouseover (mouseenter) function:

```
$("#menu-item-993").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".post-filter").show();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(".post-filter").hide();
});
```

If this doesn't override the !important try this (assuming no other dependencies in JS on post-filter class):

```
$("#menu-item-993").mouseenter(function () {
    $("div.header-menu + div").removeClass("post-filter");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $("div.header-menu + div").addClass("post-filter");
});
```

Comment: typo, should be `menu-item-993`

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
 $("#menu-item993").mouseenter(function () {
     $(".post-filter").addClass('dispaly')
 }).mouseleave(function () {
     $(".post-filter").removeClass('dispaly');
```

});

### Css

```
   .display
    {
     display:block;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add and remove the class of styling with Javascript. And you don't need `!important` on the initial css.

```
$("#menu-item-993").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".post-filter").addClass("showit");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".post-filter").removeClass("showit");
});
```

See my **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8wgz5c/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `hover` function and the `show`/`hide` functions

```js
$('#menu-item-993').hover(function(){
  $('.post-filter').show();
},function(){
  $('.post-filter').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-menu hide-for-small">
  <ul id="primary-menu" class="subtext">
    <li id="menu-item-993"><a>X</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-994"><a>Y</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-995"><a>Z</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="post-filter" style="display:none">..</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this toggleClass option

```js
$("body").on("mouseover mouseout", '#menu-item-993', function(){
    $('.post-filter').toggleClass("show hide");
});
```

```css
.post-filter {
  display: none!important;
}
.show
{
  display: block!important;
}
.hide
{
  display: hide!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-menu hide-for-small">
  <ul id="primary-menu" class="subtext">
    <li id="menu-item-993"><a>X</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-994"><a>Y</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-995"><a>Z</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="post-filter">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/0066ff/fff"></a>
<div id="title">filename.jpg</div>



#thumbnail {
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}

#thumbnail:hover + #title {
display: block;
}

#title { 
display: none;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #000000;
text-align: center;
width: 130px;
padding: 10px; 
}
```